# CL latency of unbuffered and registered RAM

Tags: memory, latency, ecc

So AFAIK, registered ram generally has a bit higher latency as going through the registers adds (usually one?) cycle.

If I have two dimms of ecc ram, one registered and one unbuffered, and both say in their specs for example CL19, is that added cycle of the registered one already included in that number? so, do both have the same clock latency or is the registerd one still slower?

Answer (score 0):

The extra latency is included in the CL number. All latencies, primary and secondary, being equal, will give you the same performance. But they are never all equal.